# Differences between "should" and "would" in subjunctive mood

Tags: grammar

How to explain the difference between:

> "Deep waters rise to the surface more quickly than they **would** if global warming were to occur."

and

> "Deep waters rise to the surface more quickly than they **should** if global warming were to occur."

Comment: None of your examples are in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: But isn't "if global warming were to occur, they would rise more quickly(or slowly)," in the subjunctive mood? So maybe in my examples the clauses following "than" in both sentences are also the same?

Comment: This use of ***should*** is OUTDATED! a century or two ago ***should*** could have been used with *exactly* the same sense as ***would*** here - to reference some "irrealis" scenario, with ***epistemic*** modality (to do with ***possibility***). But today, ***should*** is more solidly associated with ***deontic*** modality (to do with ***permission*** and ***obligation*** - what ***ought*** to happen)